# Missing $ inserted on overleaf compiler

Tags: math-mode

`For a sequence of vectors $w_{1}, w_{2},...$ obtained by the FTRL algorithm, \forall  u \in S, we say that`

Why am I getting a missing `$` inserted in this?

Comment: `$\forall u \in S$`

Comment: Correct. Some symbols that need math mode aren't in it. Also, I would suggest making it a habit to use `\(\)` instead of `$$` just so you can find errors faster, although that's just a personal preference.